# 2 Express communicate without socket

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 nodeJS folder with expressJS, I want them to communicate.

Per example : 
I have 1 express folder that work as server, and 1 as client, if 1 client connect to the server, the server check if it's first time, if it's the first time he give him a name, if it's not the first time he tell him 'hey name welcome back', I have them two to have routing and display on browser 
They need to communicate but they need to work one without other.

I want to do it without socket and tcp, only with express.

All tutorial I find on internet, it's only websocket, tcp or socket.io

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far.

Comment: For the moment i tried nothing , i don't know how to start , i try with  , client = net.connect and net.Server but someone tell me it's hard , something more easy exist with expess